# Starting new proces outside taskhost on WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7, process

I want to run a native process on Windows Phone 7 from another native process. Unfortunately I cannot use System.Diagnostic.Process because it is not supported in WP7.

The same with System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.AutomationFactory because it is a inside Silverlight library.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thank you in advance for any help

BR,
Lukasz

EDIT:

Say I have got process called "Process.exe" located in "\Windows\Process.exe".
I can start it through my PC using WPRun.exe tool but I would like to start it automatically from my phone. 
(there is no Silverlight application which could do this using AutomationFactory.)

Comment: Native process? Are you speaking of a homebrew app running on an interop-unlocked phone?

Comment: Process which is running outside TaskHost.exe

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported* way of performing such an action on the phone.

*-If you're trying to write something using more than the public SDK you may get a better response on XDADeveloeprs